# Passing a number of DataTable's rows from one blade to admin.blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm wondering about the way of passing a value from one of my blades to Admin.blade.php.

I'm using DataTable and I want to display number of datatable's rows (datatable is in some blade) in navbar (which is in Admin.blade.php code)

I managed to get the number of datatable's rows using **javasciprt** in that way:

```
var total = table.rows().count();

document.getElementById("test").value = total;
```

And get it into input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" id="test">
```

Now I really don't know what to do next, to get this number of rows in navbar, which is in Admin.blade.php file. Probably there is a way to get this value passing it to Controller.

I would be so grateful if someone manage to help me.

Comment: By default datatables fetch 10, 25, 50, 100 row per page.  So it will show you 10, 25, 50, 100 as a output. If you want to get the total table date, then use the `count()` method instead

Comment: How you are trying to pass a value from one blade to another?
Is your `admin.blade.php` file containing the other blade?

Comment: @Ion Yes, my Admin blade is containing the other blade, where datatable is placed.

Comment: @EsTeAa I've changed it to show All records, and my DataTable by default is showing all the records.